# How to Pivot SQL Pivot Mixed SQL Text and Number Data

Tags: sql, sql-server, pivot

How do I query and pivot the following table (account_book_data) from this:

| Account | Type | Title |
| --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Fantasy | Dune |
| 123 | Sports | Jordan |
| 123 | Biography | Dali |
| 456 | Fantasy | Foundation |
| 456 | Sports | Ali |
| 789 | Biography | Nelson |

To this around the type.account_book_data as new columns:

| Account | Fantasy | Sports | Biography |
| --- | --- | --- | --- |
| 123 | Dune | Jordan | Dali |
| 456 | Foundation | Ali | Null |
| 789 | Null | Null | Nelson |

I am utterly and completely stuck...

Comment: Which dbms are you using ? is this mysql ?

Comment: SQL Server Management Studio (SSMS)

Answer (score 0):

This can be done using Conditional aggregation :

```
select Account,max(case when Type = 'Fantasy' then Title end) as Fantasy,
               max(case when Type = 'Sports' then Title end) as Sports,
               max(case when Type = 'Biography' then Title end) as Biography
               
from account_book_data
group by Account
```

[Demo here](https://dbfiddle.uk/dQ_N-F5_)